# Map an array of Javascript objects to sorted unique array by a specific attribute

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object array like this where the value in the ccy field is not unique:

```
data = [{'id': 0, 'ccy': 'USD'}, ...]
```

from which I want to obtain an object array like this:

```
[{'ccy': 'USD'}, ...]
```

where the ccy values are all unique and sorted.

I have been mucking around and obtained a sorted unique array of ccy values

```
output = [...new Set(data.map(s => s.ccy))].sort();
```

but not sure how to convert that back to an array of objects

Comment: Add a `map` at the end. `.sort().map(ccy => ({ ccy }) )`

Comment: @adiga Thanks so  much for the quick response - that worked great!